# Seat allocation in python

Tags: python, optimization

I have a set of groups with a fixed number of people for each groups:

Group1: 10
Group2: 20
Group3: 18
Group4: 10

and a set of free seat per Room where each **indivisible group** could sit down:

Room1: 10
Room2: 38
Room3: 10

The output should be a potential assignment of the groups in the rooms considering the number of people in each group not splittable.
output: For instance:

```
Group1->Room1
Group2->Room2
Group3->Room2
Group4->Room3
```

How may I solve this problem in python? there is some code that could be adopted for this scenario?
of course my problem is more complicated than the one represented (it has been described as simple case just to have an idea)

Thank you

Comment: Consider using a Mixed-Integer Programming or Constraint Programming solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thank you. Do you know if there is something already implemented for such problem? just to get something and modify accordingly.

Comment: I always start from scratch. Copy-paste leads to bad models imho.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, I agree. but just to have an idea.  I'm approaching just now for the first time to this problem. If you can provide an example from your own it would be welcome as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most important part is to start with formulating a mathematical model of the problem. Here is my version:

[image]

This is basically a variation on the standard **assignment problem**.

This can be implemented easily with any Mixed-Integer Programming (MIP) or Constraint Programming (CP) solver.

Showing code is not as useful as the above model, but just as an illustration, here is an implementation using a simple CP solver (https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/).

```
from constraint import *

#
# data
# group sizes and room capacities
#
groups = {"Group1": 10, "Group2": 20, "Group3": 18, "Group4": 10}
rooms = {"Room1": 10, "Room2": 38, "Room3": 10}

#
# constraint problem
#
# variables:
#      x[i,j] = 1 if group i is assigned to room j
#               0 otherwise
# constraints:
#     sum(j, x[i,j]) = 1                     for all i   assign each group to exactly one room
#     sum(i, size[i]*x[i,j]) <= capacity[j]  for all j   capacity constraint
# 
problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(["x_%s_%s" %(i,j) for i in groups for j in rooms],[0,1])
for i in groups:
  problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(1),["x_%s_%s" %(i,j) for j in rooms])
groupSizes = [groups[i] for i in groups]
for j in rooms:
  problem.addConstraint(MaxSumConstraint(rooms[j],groupSizes),["x_%s_%s" %(i,j) for i in groups])
                        
S = problem.getSolutions()
```

Here all feasible solutions are printed. There are two of them:

```
[{'x_Group1_Room1': 1,
  'x_Group1_Room2': 0,
  'x_Group1_Room3': 0,
  'x_Group2_Room1': 0,
  'x_Group2_Room2': 1,
  'x_Group2_Room3': 0,
  'x_Group3_Room1': 0,
  'x_Group3_Room2': 1,
  'x_Group3_Room3': 0,
  'x_Group4_Room1': 0,
  'x_Group4_Room2': 0,
  'x_Group4_Room3': 1},
 {'x_Group1_Room1': 0,
  'x_Group1_Room2': 0,
  'x_Group1_Room3': 1,
  'x_Group2_Room1': 0,
  'x_Group2_Room2': 1,
  'x_Group2_Room3': 0,
  'x_Group3_Room1': 0,
  'x_Group3_Room2': 1,
  'x_Group3_Room3': 0,
  'x_Group4_Room1': 1,
  'x_Group4_Room2': 0,
  'x_Group4_Room3': 0}]
```